# Error: onActivityResult overrides nothing

Tags: android, kotlin, onactivityresult

I am programming a speech recognition app in Kotlin for Android.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    public override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val intent:Intent = Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH)
            intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM)
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE)

    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode:Int, resultCode:Int, data:Intent) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {/*do something*/  }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    }
}
```

Strangly the compiler  always finds the Error: 'onActivityResult' overrides nothing.

Documentation of Android states that result of startActivityForResult can be retrived with onActivityResult.

Now the question: how can one get the result of  speech recognition using Kotlin?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

Replace

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode:Int, resultCode:Int, data:Intent)
```

With below code, to make Intent object nullable.

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode:Int, resultCode:Int, data:Intent?)
```

As **Intent** is declared **nullable** in parent **Activity** class. Here is the sample code:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data)
```

Comment: Just right now I noticed, that the [https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics#kotlin] does it also wrong: forgetting the question mark after Intent. Was there some recent change in the library?

Comment: They add more annotation to the framework to make it more convenient with Kotlin. But the doc, as usual does not update to the new code.